# "App Name must not contain the following characters"

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, itunes

I have a problem with the application which has already been approved by Apple.
 When changing a description or pictures itunes gives me the following error:

"App Name must not contain the following characters:"

Link: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flashlight-proximity-sensor/id504641625?ls=1&mt=8

Is Apple began to reject special characters, or is it just my individual case?

Comment: @LURD - breaking a link is not "improving formatting"!

Comment: Phone them and ask or just re submit it... reviewers will differ from one to the next. If it were to get rejected again then I would definitely recommend using the Resolution Center in ITC.

Comment: @jrturton, mea culpa. Sorry, must have taken the link as part of the error message. Thanks.

Comment: I will contact Apple support, but can anyone confirm my fears before I fire the email?

Can you change anything in the application (metadata) that has a special ASCII character(s) in the main name?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so I did some tests and found that Apple is now rejecting several UTF-8 chars that were previously allowed.

If you see this error, you have probably copied your description from a website or an office program, and now there are some non-regular line-breaks, no-break spaces or other hard-to-spot special chars in it.

A simple solution is to remove all non-ascii chars from your text using a tool like [this one](https://www.janhvizdak.com/remove-non-ascii-characters-online-tool.html). After that you will have to check for lost spaces and re-add all the *allowed* UTF chars that you need, e.g. German umlauts. (So under some circumstances it might be easier to simply re-type the whole text.)